# How to order results using EntityManager from Controller in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $entities = $em
        ->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Weight')
        ->findBy(array('user' => $user), array());

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

Which is fine, gets all the weights in the database for the current user.
But how can I order the results so that all the weight entries for the same gecko id are together?
My table structure is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query for your objects using [Doctrine's QueryBuilder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder).
Something like this:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Weight');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('w')
    ->where('w.user = :user')
    ->orderBy('w.geckoId ASC')
    ->getQuery();

$query->setParameter(':user', $user);

$entities = $query->getResult();
```

If you want additional ordering, you can do something like:

```
->orderBy('w.geckoId ASC, w.weight ASC, w.id ASC')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will test it when i am home as i have to go back to work now :)

Comment: The point is i would like all to show all weights in the database, but grouped together by the same gecko id rather than being sporadically placed in the returned list. I will try this later on though

Comment: @AndyHolmes I see, then I understand you are looking for *sorting*, not for *grouping* - in natural language, someone _might_ understand that by "grouping the entities by gecko ID" you mean "putting all those with the same gecko ID together", but that's **NOT** what GROUP BY means in a DB context - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277460/what-is-the-difference-between-group-by-and-order-by-in-sql

Answer (score 3):

You should create your own repository and use the `addGroupBy` function on the querybuilder. Example:

```
class WeightRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getGroupedByGeckoId(User $user)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('weight');

        $qb->select('whateverYouWant');
        $qb->andWhere('weight.user = :user');
        $qb->setParameter('user', $user);

        $qb->addGroupBy('weight.geckoId');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will test it when i am home as i have to go back to work now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also order by using the repository object itself like so:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $entities = $em
        ->getRepository('BreedrGeckoBundle:Weight')
        ->findBy(array('user' => $user), array('geckoId' => 'ASC'));

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't comment on if this is a good option or not at this question is over 6 years old