# two tables in one SQL, query

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have two tables

```
 ID_USER | USERNAME
   1       Max
   2       Jean
   3       Carl
   4       Sophie
```

and

```
ID_MONEY | ID_USER | MONEY
  1           4      1000
  2           2      1500
  3           3      1250
  4           1      920
```

I want to execute the second table SQL and order the results by username (alphabetically), in order to get this:

```
Carl have: 1250$
Jean have: 1500$
Max  have: 920$
Sophie have: 1000$
```

What type of query sould I execute?
I tried,

```
SELECT * 
FROM $table_users 
WHERE id_user='$id_user' 
ORDER BY (SELECT username FROM $table_money WHERE id_user='$id_user') ASC
```

but not results as expected.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to do. *I want to execute the second table*: this does not mean anything, a table cannot be executed. Anyway, it seems you need [`join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: Not native english speaker ma friend. apologyse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `INNER JOIN`. This can be done using joins, or with the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT USERNAME, MONEY
FROM $table_users
JOIN $table_money USING (ID_USER)
ORDER BY USERNAME
```

or

```
SELECT USERNAME, MONEY
FROM $table_users, $table_money
WHERE $table_users.ID_USER = $table_money.ID_USER
ORDER BY USERNAME
```

Comment: I get the order I want after using the second statement btw I have to use  GROUP BY not ORDER BY, the first one doesnt retrieve results as expected, are the same? thanks

Comment: Whoops, there was a typo. I meant to `JOIN $table_money`. They are equivalent. The first is called an explicit join, and the second is called an implicit join. MySQL will interpret them exactly the same.

Comment: If you want the results to be sorted, use ORDER BY. You may benefit from reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277460/what-is-the-difference-between-group-by-and-order-by-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

I guess table_money might have multiple money values for the same user and you would want total.

```
SELECT table_users.ID_USER, table_users.USERNAME, SUM(table_money.MONEY)
FROM table_users  INNER JOIN table_money ON table_users.ID_USER = table_money.ID_USER
GROUP BY table_users.ID_USER, table_users.USERNAME
ORDER BY table_users.USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am using concatenation function to join the strings.

```
select CONCAT(tu.username,' have: ',tm.money,'$') as RESULT
from [$table_users] as tu
inner join [$table_money] as tm
on tu.ID_USER = tm.ID_USER
order by RESULT ASC;
```

OUTPUT:-

[image]